# Flutter : Mapping two lists toegther

Tags: dictionary, flutter

Here I am mapping only one list, But the case is that I want to map two lists together so the date appear and after that the photo like in the picture here. So, I want to know How can I make a map of list1 and dates, which is the two lists I have. that they will be only one list which I can use in the body of the scaffold ? [image]

```
List<Meal> _list1=[Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla'),
Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh',name: 'chekin filla')];
List<Date> dates = [Date(dat:'20th of september 2018'),Date(dat:'21th of september 2018'),Date(dat:'22th of september 2018'),
Date(dat:'23th of september 2018')
,Date(dat: '24th of september 2018')];
Map<Object,Object> list2= {dates,_list1};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('listviewww'),
      ),
      body:
        ListView( children:_list2
        .map((element){
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              child: Text('My name is ayaaaaaaaaaaa '),
          ),
            Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
           constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 300.0),
           decoration: new BoxDecoration(
           border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal( left:Radius.circular(30.0) ,right:Radius.circular(30.0) ),
           image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage('assets/food.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.cover,),),
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child:Center(
        child:Text('HELLfffffffffffO')
      )
      )
            ], 

      );  
        }).toList()

     ) 
     );
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to map the two lists to create a `ListView`. Just use [ListView.builder()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    var meal = _list1[index];
    var date = dates[index];
    return Text("Here comes your item with $meal and $date");
  },
);
```

Comment: For this to work both the date and meal must be of the same length. Otherwise, you will run into out RangeError of an index.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to do something like that. Check below, you can [run this code in Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) (you'll need to copy and paste it).

```
class Meal {
  Meal({this.dis, this.name});
  final String dis;
  final String name;
}

class Date {
  Date({this.dat});
  final String dat;
}

void main() {

  List<Meal> _list1 = [
    Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh', name: 'chekin filla'),
    Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh', name: 'chekin filla'),
    Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh', name: 'chekin filla'),
    Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh', name: 'chekin filla'),
    Meal(dis:'it is a chicken sandwichh', name: 'chekin filla')
  ];

  List<Date> dates = [
    Date(dat:'20th of september 2018'),
    Date(dat:'21th of september 2018'),
    Date(dat:'22th of september 2018'),
    Date(dat:'23th of september 2018'),
    Date(dat:'24th of september 2018')
  ];

  // this is where the mapping will be placed
  Map<Date, Meal> mealsEachDay = new Map();

  // and here the relationship between the dates and the meals is done
  for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)
    mealsEachDay[dates[i]] = _list1[i];

  List<String> yourObjects = mealsEachDay.keys.map((date) {
    return "The date is '${date.dat}' and the meal is '${mealsEachDay[date].dis}'";
  }).toList();

  yourObjects.forEach((s) {
    print(s);    
  });
}
```

But yet this is not yet worth much. You'll have to understand better the relationship between the objects, lists and maps.

Check this other example below and run it in dartpad as well. For each date there are meals and it's easier to go through them. Another improvement is also not using dates as text.

```
class Meal {
  Meal({this.dis, this.name});
  final String dis;
  final String name;
}

class MealDate {
  MealDate({this.date, this.meals});
  final DateTime date;
  final List<Meal> meals;
}

void main() {

  List<MealDate> mealsForEachDate = [
    MealDate(
      date: DateTime(2018, 9, 20),
      meals: [
        Meal(name: 'eggs', dis: 'scrambed eggs'),
        Meal(name: 'chiken filet', dis: 'chicken sandwich'),
      ]
    ),
    MealDate(
      date: DateTime(2018, 9, 21),
      meals: [
        Meal(name: 'bread', dis: 'bread and water'),
      ]
    ),
    MealDate(
      date: DateTime(2018, 9, 22),
      meals: [
        Meal(name: 'rice', dis: 'rice and beans'),
      ]
    ),
  ];

  mealsForEachDate.forEach((date) {
    print("[Date ${date.date}]");
    print("  Number of meals ${date.meals.length}");
    var n = 0;
    date.meals.forEach((meal) {
      print("    Meal ${++n}: ${meal.dis}");
    });
    print("\n");
  });
}
```

Good luck and never stop coding!

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm gathering, you have two lists each with the same number elements. The first list describes the items (name, display etc), while the second is the date.

You're trying to display this in a list, but can't because you have two lists of information.

The simplest answer to this is to make the two lists into one list, i.e. combine the item description and the date. You can make a simple class that has a date and description as fields.

You could theoretically make use of the Tuple library and make up a tuple of the two bits of information, but that hardly seems necessary and making a data object is more concise anyways.

If I've misinterpreted your question, feel free to let me know. The other possibility I could see is that you're trying to make a list with dates as headings, with one or more items under each date.